# YouTube video plays fine on Youtube website but plays back choppy in WP blog regardless of browser

Tags: video, youtube, wordpress

Anyway... I have placed a video welcome message in my WP blog homepage.  It is nothing huge or special but there it is.

Now it plays back OK in youtube ( recorded on my phone so not spectacular quality but no horrible either). In my blog the playback is crappy. Audio is fine but the picture is all jerky and stops and starts etc. I thought it might be browser related ( because my research shows that playback issues can be browser related) ...but I test everything in three browsers ( chrome, FF and ie) and, in this case, I had similar problems in all of them....plus the browsers had no problem playing back on youtube, just in my blog, so the browsers don't appear to be the source of the problem.

I switched from the iframe embed code to shortcode [video src" etc..."] which displays better in WP than youtube standard embed and is more easily customized. I thought since it was WP specific it might work better.

Playback appears to be slightly ( very slightly) better in Chrome but there is no difference in the two other browsers. I have to conclude that the problem is with WP or my host but I am not sure. I have been trying to solve this for two days but my online searches regarding this issue have not yielded any relevant results so far. I have no problem playing back or streaming video as a rule so I don't think it is my laptop.